# Variable check and summary out

Tags: sas

### Problem/Question

I'm trying to do a simple check on on a list of variables in a data set (revenue, costs, profits, and vcosts) that grabs the largest and second largest from each variable, checks if their total is greater than 90% of the sum of the variable, and if so, flags that variable.  I want to also check that the largest variable is not larger than 60% of the total sum.

I got a bit of help from this [Macro that outputs table with testing results of SAS table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241672/macro-that-outputs-table-with-testing-results-of-sas-table)[Macro that outputs table with testing results of SAS table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241672/macro-that-outputs-table-with-testing-results-of-sas-table) but now I'm trying to answer a much more basic question.  This doesn't seem to hard, but I can't figure out how to setup the basic table at the end.

I know all the variable names.

Here is a sample dataset I've created : https://www.dropbox.com/s/x575w5d551uu47p/dataset%20%281%29.csv?dl=0

### Desired Output

I would like to turn this basic table :

[image]

Into another table like this :

[image]

### Reproducible example

```
/* Create some dummy data with three variables to assess */
data have;
    do firm = 1 to 3;
        revenue = rand("uniform");
        costs = rand("uniform");
        profits = rand("uniform");
        vcost = rand("uniform");
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: How many records do you have in real scenario?

Comment: @NEOmen What do you mean by records?  If you mean observations, then thousands.  If you mean variables, then dozens.

Comment: By records I meant observations...individuals lines in a dataset are generally called records

Comment: @NEOmen Sorry, I've only known them as obs.

Comment: If your dataset has values like  - 100, 100, 99 then which would be first and second largest - 100 and 100 or 100 and 99?

Comment: @NEOmen Given the nature of the data, I highly doubt any one firm would have the same number.  But if so, then 100 100 as those are the highest...thanks

Comment: This is not, still, a good question.  There isn't a clear question in the question, and this ultimately is still a 'here is a spec, please do my job'.  Again, unless you're paying $100 an hour, this isn't appropriate.  While apparently several people here are willing to work for free, in general we need a concrete problem that is not a "output needed" but a "how do I do something" that's specific and focused and based either on code you've written or something that is likely to be answered with a particular function or something generally useful, not code for your particular job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment on the previous answer. It looks like top_2_total is sum of the 2 maximum total values. For that purpose you would need to code some extra step. I'm using proc transpose and a datastep to get what was already acheieved in the previous answer. I have coded PROC SUMMARY to get the top 2 maximum total values and reusing the dataset to create the final answer. Let me know if it helps.

```
data have;
    do firm = 1 to 3;
        revenue = rand("uniform");
        costs = rand("uniform");
        profits = rand("uniform");
        vcost = rand("uniform");
        output;
    end;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=want prefix=top_;
    var revenue--vcost;
run;

data want;
set want end=eof;
    array top(*) top_3-top_1;
    call sortn(of top[*]);
    total=sum(of top[*]);
run;
/* Getting the maximum 2 total values using PROC SUMMARY*/
proc summary data=want nway;
    output out=total_top_2_rec(drop=_:) idgroup(max(total) out[2](total)=);
run;

data want;
/* Loop to get the values from previous step and generate TOP_2_TOTAL variable */
if _n_=1 then set total_top_2_rec;
    top_2_total=sum(total_1,total_2);

set want;
    if sum(top_1,top_2) > 0.9  * top_2_total then Flag90=1; else Flag90=0;
    if top_1 > top_2_total * 0.6 then Flag60=1; else Flag60=0;

drop total_1 total_2;
run;

proc print data=want;run;
```

**EDIT :** I have added a logic before my PROC TRANSPOSE where you can add the variables to consider for the calculation and rest is done by the code. No manual changes would be required to be done by code executor after that. The variables should be entered as space delimited list.

```
data have;
infile 'C:\dataset (1).csv' missover dsd dlm=',' firstobs=2;
input firm v1 v2 v3;
run;

/* add/remove columns here to consider variable */
%let variable_to_consider=v1 
                          v2 
                          v3
                          ;

%let variable_to_consider=%cmpres(&variable_to_consider);
proc sql noprint;
  select count(*) into : obs_count from have;
quit;
%let obs_count=&obs_count;

proc transpose data=have out=want prefix=top_;
    var &variable_to_consider; 
run;

data want;
set want end=eof;
    array top(*) top_&obs_count.-top_1;
    x=dim(top);
    call sortn(of top[*]);
    total=sum(of top[*]);

keep total top_1 top_2 _name_;
run;

/* Getting the maximum 2 total values using PROC SUMMARY*/
proc summary data=want nway;
    output out=total_top_2_rec(drop=_:) idgroup(max(total) out[2](total)=);
run;

data want;
/* Loop to get the values from previous step and generate TOP_2_TOTAL variable */
if _n_=1 then set total_top_2_rec;
    top_2_total=sum(total_1,total_2);

set want;
    if sum(top_1,top_2) > 0.9  * top_2_total then Flag90=1; else Flag90=0;
    if top_1 > top_2_total * 0.6 then Flag60=1; else Flag60=0;

drop total_1 total_2;
run;

proc print data=want;run;
```

**EDIT 2014-04-05 :** As discussed, i have updated the logic and fixed the issues. Below is the updated code.

```
data have1;
    do firm = 1 to 3;
        revenue = rand("uniform");
        costs = rand("uniform");
        profits = rand("uniform");
        vcost = rand("uniform");
        output;
    end;
run;

data have2;
infile 'dataset (1).csv' missover dsd dlm=',' firstobs=2;
input firm v1 v2 v3;
run;
/* add/remove columns here to consider variable */

%macro mymacro(input_dataset= ,output_dataset=, variable_to_consider=);

%let variable_to_consider=%cmpres(&variable_to_consider);
proc sql noprint;
  select count(*) into : obs_count from &input_dataset;
quit;
%let obs_count=&obs_count;

proc transpose data=&input_dataset out=&output_dataset prefix=top_;
    var &variable_to_consider; 
run;

data &output_dataset;
set &output_dataset end=eof;
    array top(*) top_&obs_count.-top_1;
    x=dim(top);
    call sortn(of top[*]);
    total=sum(of top[*]);

top_2_total=sum(top_1, top_2);
    if sum(top_1,top_2) > 0.9  * total then Flag90=1; else Flag90=0;
    if top_1 > total * 0.6 then Flag60=1; else Flag60=0;

keep total top_1 top_2 _name_ top_2_total total Flag60 Flag90;

run;
%mend mymacro;

%mymacro(input_dataset=have1, output_dataset=want1 ,variable_to_consider=revenue costs profits vcost)
%mymacro(input_dataset=have2, output_dataset=want2 ,variable_to_consider=v1 v2 v3 )


proc print data=want1;run;
proc print data=want2;run;
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works, but I only need the top 2 printed.  When I add additional variables and observations from a data set it prints them all out and no longer ranks them, so top1 and top2 are not the top observations for each variable.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't working when I apply it to a much larger data set.  I've added the sample data set to the question.

Comment: my bad, I mixed up my things. multitasking can really mess up things sometime. I realized the mistake and fixed it. try again!

Comment: Actually, I was just playing with this and noticed that the top_2_total is the exact same, so something is off.  Running your first example will show this.

Comment: Can you check the log after you run the code. I'm guessing that you might have entered variable in the %let statement that is not on the dataset.That could be the only reason why top_2_total be same for 2 consecutive run of code with different data. and the proc print would be printing the older result.

Comment: I checked all the code and the variables in the %let statement are all correct.  The top1 and top2 variables are correct, but the the sum of both is the same down...If you run the first example with the random generated data it will produce this result.

Comment: ok, i think there is a confusion, can you let me know the top_2_total value for the data that is posted in the question..that might help

Comment: Top_1 (Largest value) , Top_2 (Second Largest Value), Top_2_Total (Sum of largest value and second largest value), Total (Sum of obs. for each variable)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74486/discussion-between-sushil-and-amstell).

Comment: I've run into problems with the macro on a larger data set and giving me errors.  Was hoping you could help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297402/macro-not-loading-data-set?noredirect=1#comment50586202_31297402

Answer (score 1):

The hard part here is extracting the top 2 values for each variable. This is simple in most implementations of SQL, but in SAS I don't think `proc sql` supports the `select top n` syntax.

I can think of several possible ways of doing this:

1. Sort the dataset in descending order by each variable of interest, retrieve the values from the first 2 observations, transpose, and append them all together - this very inefficient due to multiple sorts, and it isn't much simpler than the other approaches.
2. Write a (fairly complex) data step to extract the top 2 values for each variable.
3. Get proc univariate to extract the top values for you and then transpose the output dataset into the right format.

**Data step approach**

```
data top2;
  array v{4} revenue costs profits vcost;
  array top1{4} (4*0);
  array top2{4} (4*0);
  set have end = eof;
  do i = 1 to 4;
    if v[i] > top1[i] then do;
      top2[i] = top1[i];
      top1[i] = v[i];
    end;
    if top2[i] < v[i] < top1[i] then top2[i] = v[i];
  end;
  length varname $8;
  if eof then do i = 1 to 4;
    varname = vname(v[i]);
    top_1    = top1[i];
    top_2    = top2[i];
    top_2_total = top_1 + top_2;
    output;
  end;
  keep varname top_:;
run;
```

**Proc univariate approach**

```
ods _all_ close;
ods output extremeobs = extremeobs(keep = varname high);
proc univariate data = have(drop = firm);
run;
ods listing;

data top2_b;
    set extremeobs;
    by varname notsorted;
    if first.varname then do;
        i = 0;
        call missing(top_2);
    end;
    i + 1;
    retain top_2;
    if i = 4 then top_2 = high;
    if i = 5 then do;
        top_1 = high;
        top_2_total = top_1 + top_2;
        output;
    end;
    drop i high;
run;
```

Once you've got this you can merge it with your existing simple table from proc means / proc summary and compute any further measures of interest.

Comment: Thanks.  This is very close, but how would I add the checks...i'd tried adding     `sum = Total;`   `Flag90 = top_2_total >  Total* 0.9;`    `Flag60 = top_1 > Total * 0.6;` but it won't print those on the summary table.  How would I go about adding the checks in the data step approach?  Thanks for a great answer

Comment: Any additional help?  Thanks

Comment: I've gotten this far, but still need to get the sum and check the calculations with sum of all variables .........  `data top2;
set top2;
if sum(top_1 + top_2) > 0.9 * top_2_total then Flag90=1;
else Flag90=0;
if top_1 > top_2_total * 0.6 then Flag60=1;
else Flag60=0;
run;`

Comment: based on your previous comment, your varaible flag90 would always be equal to 0 because top_2_total = top_1+top_2 and you are checking sum(top_1 + top_2) > 0.9 * top_2_total which would always be false. can you please recheck the logic for flag90

Comment: @sushil Yes I know, this is what I'm trying to fix....I want top_2_total to instead be equal to the sum of the variable listed....top_2_total should be the sum of the variable so that the 90% rule applies, but I can't figure it out....thanks

Answer (score 1):

The flag1 and flag2 in the last step will have a positive integer for values with numerator greater than or equal to the denominator and zero if the numerator less than denominator.

```
data have(drop=firm);
    do firm = 1 to 4;
        VarName = 'Variable';
        revenue = rand("uniform");
        costs = rand("uniform");
        profits = rand("uniform");
        vcost = rand("uniform");
        output;
    end;
run;

Proc Transpose data=have out=transout
name=Variable
prefix=Var_;
run;

options Mprint;

%Macro calcflag(Varlist);
proc sql;
create table outtable as
select Variable,
sum(&Varlist) as Sum_var,
Largest(1,&Varlist) as Top_1,
Largest(2,&Varlist) as Top_2,
sum(Largest(1,&Varlist),Largest(2,&Varlist)) as Top_2_total,
floor(sum(Largest(1,&Varlist),Largest(2,&Varlist))/(sum(&Varlist)*0.9)) as flag1,
floor(Largest(1,&Varlist)/(sum(&Varlist)*0.6)) as flag2 
from transout;
quit;
%mend;

%calcflag(%str(Var_1,Var_2,Var_3,Var_4));
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works, but I don't need to print out all of the variables, just sum, top1, top2, flag90, and flag60 for each variable.  So no var1-var4

Comment: I edited the select list to remove Var_1 to Var_4. Hope that works. As I said earlier, the two steps can be compressed into one if you have a huge dataset. This is the easiest method I can think of that does not involve any sorts, merges etc. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.  I do have a large dataset.  How would i compress the two steps?

Comment: Done; I also had the 0.6 and 0.9 multiples incorrectly previously. I hope I have understood it right this time!

Comment: Could you please check if you checking against the right input values for Var_1 through Var_4? Sum_Var, Top_1 and Top_2 are the ones I am pretty confident are correct in the above SQL. I checked on excel too, it checks out.

Comment: This is what I'm getting for revenue : 1.45132 0.67516 1.33275 1 0 ... so sum_var is smaller than the sum of top1 (0.67516) and top2 (1.33275), which doesn't make sense.  The sum_var should be the total sum of the variable, then top1 and top2 are top 2 variables

Comment: I have calculated top_2 as the sum of the top 2 variables, so that scenario is possible where sum of top 2 variables + top variable is greater than the sum of 4 variables... That was my understanding from other discussions. I have edited top_2 to be second biggest value now. Pls. Check

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in the question.  I see now what is going on.  Could you edit the sql so that there is a total, top1, top2, top2_total ?  Where total is total sum of variable, top1 is largest variable, top2 is second largest, and top2_total is the total of top1 and top2.  This would be ideal.  I like the use of sql... thanks

Comment: Edited to add top_2_total.

Comment: Yup that looks good and is working....I like the use of sql...can this be scaled to assign variables from a data set to do the checks on?  Whereby I could set which variables I need checked?  The sql seems to only apply to the 4 variables.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You can assign the list to a macro and then replace the variable list in all locations easily.

Comment: I added the macro - all you need to do is to change the macro call according to what variables you need, make sure they are available in the input dataset:
%calcflag(%str(Var_1,Var_2,Var_3,Var_4));

Comment: Great thanks...so I'd just replace Var_1--Var_4 with all the variables I need to call?  In the sample dataset I provided up top, there are variables V1, V2, V3....would I just throw those in the macro call?  I just tried it and it's not workign

Comment: You would need to do two things: **1.** change the dataset name in the sql in place of 'transout' to whatever name you have and **2.** change the macro call to: %calcflag(%str(Total,Mean,Median,StDev));

Comment: Here's what I did - Import data: `proc import datafile="/folders/myfolders/dataset.csv"
     out=have
     dbms=csv
     replace;
     getnames=yes;
run;`   `%calcflag(%str(V1, V2, V3));`  and changed `from have` But it's telling me missing `Variable` in column   do I need to change `select Variable,` in the macro?

Comment: Is the file dataset.csv the same as the 'basic table' you have listed at the top? or is the basic table transposed from the dataset.csv? Can you tell me what are the field names (from left to right) on the first row in dataset.csv?

Comment: The basic table is different from the posted dataset.csv as in the variables and obs are different.  This was a test dataset I made to make sure all the checks are working correctly.  I was trying to get it working on my own, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Can you tell me what are the field names (from left to right) on the first row in dataset.csv?

Comment: the variable names are : V1, V2, V3

Comment: Remove "Variable," in the SQL - that was for a column that does not exist in the datset you have now.

Comment: Please take this to chat rather than using comments this way.  Thanks.

Comment: I would love take it to chat, but apparently, I have far too few reputation points to use chat. Sorry.

Comment: @Joe I'd love to chat too, but with enautic low rep, we can't chat

Comment: Now that I've taken out `variable` it's listing all my variables....here is my code http://pastebin.com/M0ezLuVQ

Comment: If you want to just read the output instead of creating the table and then doing a proc print, you can remove 'create table outtable as' from the SQL. Then it will just print the output.

Comment: Thanks...i don't mind the `proc print` right now, but I'm confused as to why it's printing all the variables ... here is the output...http://pastebin.com/RFPUSp5k

Comment: As far as I see, the list is exactly what I'd expect it to return. I thought that is what you wanted as well.

Comment: There are only 3 variables, so i would expect it to return the sum, top1 and top2, and top2_total for each variable (3), with the flag if it met the criteria....so the table would only be 3x6

Comment: I worked on a completely different understanding of your table as per your question, I don't think this method would work for your question. Sorry and good luck!