# Macro not loading data set

Tags: sas

### Previous Posts :

[Variable check and summary out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380819/variable-check-and-summary-out)

[Macro that outputs table with testing results of SAS table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241672/macro-that-outputs-table-with-testing-results-of-sas-table)

### Question/Problem

From the previous posts, I thought I was able to run the macro and produce the desired results.  However, after finally getting a report back that the output is not working I'm really confused as to why I'm getting the error that there were missing variables.  It appears as if the data set is not being loaded after sub-setting.  I'm able to process basic summary statistic tables, but when I load the macro the output is not working.

Why is the data set not loading?  Does a macro require a certain type of data set?

Note : A limitation is that I do not have access to the data set, so I must send code to be run and won't get results for a few days.  It's a very long and frustrating process, but I'm sure some can relate.

The code that is causing problems is the macro (in beginning of code) and the very last section which calls the macro with the data set.

### Error Log :

[image]
[image]

### Code :

```
# Filename : Census2007_Hawaii_BearingCoffee_BigIsland.sas

/******************************************************************
 Clearance Test Macro
    input_dataset  - desired dataset which variables are located
    output_dataset - an output table with test results
    variable_to_consider - list of variables to compute test on
*******************************************************************/

%macro clearance_test(input_dataset= ,output_dataset=, variable_to_consider=);

%let variable_to_consider=%cmpres(&variable_to_consider);
proc sql noprint;
  select count(*) into : obs_count from &input_dataset;
quit;
%let obs_count=&obs_count;

proc transpose data=&input_dataset out=&output_dataset prefix=top_;
    var &variable_to_consider; 
run;

data &output_dataset;
set &output_dataset end=eof;
    array top(*) top_&obs_count.-top_1;
    x=dim(top);
    call sortn(of top[*]);
    total=sum(of top[*]);

top_2_total=sum(top_1, top_2);
    if sum(top_1,top_2) > 0.9  * total then Flag90=1; else Flag90=0;
    if top_1 > total * 0.6 then Flag60=1; else Flag60=0;

keep total top_1 top_2 _name_ top_2_total total Flag60 Flag90;

run;
%mend mymacro;

/***********************************************************************/

*Define file path statics;
Libname def 'P:\Hawaii_Arita\John_Hawaii_Coffee\Datasets';
Libname abc "P:\Hawaii_Arita\John_Hawaii_Coffee\Datasets";
option obs=max;

/* Initialize database */

DATA def.Census2007_Hawaii_Coffee;
    SET abc.census2007_hawaii_SubSet_Coffee;
    **<create the variables used in the macro> **;
RUN;

/* Clearance Test Results */

%clearance_test(input_dataset=def.census2007_hawaii_SubSet_Coffee, output_dataset=test_data ,variable_to_consider= OIR OIRO ROA ROAO SProfit 
LProfit SProfitAcre LProfitAcre Profitable MachineandRent UtilityandFuel LaborH LaborO FertilizerandChem MaintandCustom 
Interest Tax Dep Others TFPE_cal operators workers operatorsandworkers)
```

### A Complete/Verifiable Example :

This has been tested on the remote machine and works perfectly.

```
/* Create test data set*/
data business_data;
do firm = 1 to 3;
revenue = rand("uniform");
costs = rand("uniform");
profits = rand("uniform");
vcost = rand("uniform");
output;
end;
run;
/******************************************************************
Clearance Test Macro
input_dataset - desired dataset which variables are located
output_dataset - an output table with test results
variable_to_consider - list of variables to compute test on
*******************************************************************/
%macro clearance_test(input_dataset= ,output_dataset=, variable_to_consider=);
%let variable_to_consider=%cmpres(&variable_to_consider);
proc sql noprint;
select count(*) into : obs_count from &input_dataset;
quit;
%let obs_count=&obs_count;
proc transpose data=&input_dataset out=&output_dataset prefix=top_;
var &variable_to_consider;
run;
data &output_dataset;
set &output_dataset end=eof;
array top(*) top_&obs_count.-top_1;
x=dim(top);
call sortn(of top[*]);
total=sum(of top[*]);
top_2_total=sum(top_1, top_2);
if sum(top_1,top_2) > 0.9 * total then Flag90=1; else Flag90=0;
if top_1 > total * 0.6 then Flag60=1; else Flag60=0;
keep total top_1 top_2 _name_ top_2_total total Flag60 Flag90;
run;
%mend mymacro;
/* Print summary table, run macro, and print clearance test table */
PROC MEANS data = business_data n sum mean median std;
VAR revenue costs profits vcost;
RUN;
%clearance_test(input_dataset=business_data, output_dataset=test_data ,
variable_to_consider=revenue costs profits vcost)
proc print data = test_data; run;
```

Comment: I removed most of the code as it didn't have any bearing on the question.

Comment: @Joe Thanks!  I was just thinking I should remove the sub-setting section, but you deleted the file paths, which I think are relevant.

Comment: The file paths are hardly relevant: they're only useful on your machine, after all, and they're not related to the error [unless you're using the wrong paths, but how would we know that or be able to help with that?]  And the data step and subsequent proc means are irrelevant as they don't provide any input to the macro.

Comment: Wait, maybe the data step was relevant.  Are you intending the data step's result be the input to the macro?  Because it's not currently, currently the macro takes the `set` dataset (the initial input).

Comment: @Joe Yes I want the input to be the data set that was subset.

Comment: Turn `option mprint;` on so you can see exactly what the OUTPUT of the macro is.

Comment: Then why didn't you pass that name to the macro?  `%clearance_test(input_dataset=def.census2007_hawaii_SubSet_Coffee` means you're sending the initial dataset, not `DATA def.Census2007_Hawaii_Coffee`.  Is the problem that you don't have those names on the data step properly? Or is this just a typo putting code in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your macro definition on the %mend is mymacro not clearance_test. You shouldn't need the %cmpres though I can't see what it's doing.  You're missing a RUN on your data step, which may or may not have been removed. You're calling the macro with the incorrect dataset or library, it should be abc.census2007_hawaii_subset_coffee or def.census2007_hawaii_coffee.

Comment: @Joe I sent `input_dataset=def.census2007_hawaii_SubSet_Coffee` to the macro because that contains the variables that I sub-set.  The initial data set (`def.Census2007_Hawaii_Coffee`) does not contain those variables.

Comment: @Amstell You're wrong, though, at least per what you initially posted (though what you initially posted is also somewhat inconsistent).  The new dataset that has the new variables doesn't have the word 'subset' in it.  You might've made that error copying it over to SO, but at least what you posted doesn't have what I'd call the correct dataset.  And the error agrees with me...

Comment: Look at the data step again.  `data def.Census2007_Hawaii_Coffee; set abc.Census2007_Hawaii_Subset_Coffee;`  That creates a new dataset, `Census2007_Hawaii_Coffee`, from an older dataset, `Census2007_Hawaii_Subset_Coffee`.

Comment: @Joe I'm confused then; `data def.Census2007_Hawaii_Coffee` is located in the directory and not the Subset_Coffee data...How is that possible?

Comment: That's rather hard to tell from here.  Again, this could be a typo (either in your real code or what you posted).  But, assuming the data step above is supposed to create these variables you're interested in, it's not then being passed to the macro, again assuming everything you posted is accurate.

Comment: I added a clarification to the data step to point out its purpose (as it seems important now) - if that's wrong please adjust.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for your help.  This is an exact copy past from the code I submitted.  Are you suggesting the macro should be this instead? `input_dataset=def.Census2007_Hawaii_Coffee`

Comment: Well, or your data step is incorrectly written, and it should be `data abc.Census2007_Hawaii_Subset_Coffee; set def.Census2007_Hawaii_Coffee;`, but it's hard to tell without seeing what you're working with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82727/discussion-between-amstell-and-joe).

Comment: Joe and @Reeza  : Does this pastebin code look accurate? I've changed the data step and think this is correct. I appreciate your help. http://pastebin.com/0pTi0iV8

Comment: No. You didn't fix many of the mistakes I pointed out in my earlier post. %mend for starters.

Comment: @Reeza Yes you're right.  Sorry.  That has been corrected.  Is the data step and macro call at the bottom correct though? http://pastebin.com/Lus0Qm8D

Answer (score 1):

This is where a minimal, complete verifiable example (MCVE) would be helpful for testing whether your problem is a problem with the code, or the data.

Here's the code above, but with a `SASHELP` dataset (those are built-in to SAS so everyone has them).

```
%macro clearance_test(input_dataset= ,output_dataset=, variable_to_consider=);

%let variable_to_consider=%cmpres(&variable_to_consider);
proc sql noprint;
  select count(*) into : obs_count from &input_dataset;
quit;
%let obs_count=&obs_count;

proc transpose data=&input_dataset out=&output_dataset prefix=top_;
    var &variable_to_consider; 
run;

data &output_dataset;
set &output_dataset end=eof;
    array top(*) top_&obs_count.-top_1;
    x=dim(top);
    call sortn(of top[*]);
    total=sum(of top[*]);

top_2_total=sum(top_1, top_2);
    if sum(top_1,top_2) > 0.9  * total then Flag90=1; else Flag90=0;
    if top_1 > total * 0.6 then Flag60=1; else Flag60=0;

keep total top_1 top_2 _name_ top_2_total total Flag60 Flag90;

run;
%mend clearance_test;


%clearance_test(input_dataset=sashelp.cars, output_dataset=work.test, variable_to_consider=mpg_city mpg_highway);
```

That's the exact macro, just using a different input dataset.  It works correctly on my machine (the flag variables are meaningless since the data isn't right for them, but the code works).

Run the same on your colleague's machine, and if it runs, then you know the data is the problem (ie, the dataset doesn't have the variables you think it does).  If it doesn't run, then you have some other problem (perhaps an issue with how it's being submitted, maybe you end up with spurious characters or something).

Comment: I have run a test data set on the remote machine first to make sure everything is working correctly (See previous posts).  Then I edited the needed code appropriately and that is where I am running into problems.  I should mention that the summary tables have all the variables that were subset, but the macro says they are missing

Comment: I've added the exact MCVE code I tested with to the answer.